# Given two functions, Is one function the big-O of another function?

Tags: big-o

My question refers to the big-Oh notation in algorithm analysis. While Big-Oh seems to be a math question, it's much useful in algorithm analysis.

Suppose two functions are defined below:

- f(n) = 2( to the power n) when n is even
- f(n) = n when n is odd
- g(n) = n when n is even
- g(n) = 2( to the power n) when n is odd.

For the above two functions which one is big-Oh of other? Or whether any function is not a Big-Oh of another function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case,

- f ∉ O(g), and
- g ∉ O(f).

This is because no matter what constants *N* and *k* you pick,

- there exists *i* ≥ *N* such that f(i) > k g(i), and
- there exists *j* ≥ *N* such that g(j) > k f(j).

Comment: +1 on the assumption you will fix your minor typo in the last line

Comment: Thanks. I think you convinced me.

Answer (score 0):

The Big-Oh relationship is quite specific in that one function is, after a finite n, always larger than the other.

Is this true here? If so, give such a `n`.  If not, you should prove it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually [Big-O and Big-Theta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_theta#Related_asymptotic_notations) notations get confused.

A layman attempt at definition could be that Big-O means that one function is growing **as fast or faster** than another one, i.e. that given a large enough n, `f(n)<=k*g(n)` where k is some constant. That means that if f(x) = 2x^3, then it is in O(x^3), O(x^4), O(2^x), O(x!) etc..

Big-Theta means that one function is growing **as fast** as another one, with neither one being able to "outgrow" the other, or, `k1*g(n)<=f(n)<=k2*g(n)` for some k1 and k2. In programming terms that means that these two functions have the same level of complexity. If f(x) = 2x^3, then it is in Θ(x^3), as for example, if k1=1, and k2=3, `1*x^3 < 2*x^3 < 3*x^3`

In my experience whenever programmers are talking about Big-O, the discussion is actually about Big-Θ, as we are concerned more with the *as fast as* part more, than in the *no faster than* part.

That said, if two functions with different Θ's are combined, as in your example, the larger one - (Θ(2^n) - swallows the smaller - Θ(n), so both `f` and `g` have the exact same Big-O and Big-Θ complexities. In this case, it's both correct that

```
f(n) = O(g(n)), also f(n) = Θ(g(n))
g(n) = O(f(n)), also g(n) = Θ(f(n))
```

so, as they have the same complexity, they are O and Θ bound by each other.